# SwipeRefreshLayout no animation on fragment creation

Tags: android, animation, android-recyclerview, swiperefreshlayout

I'm using `android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout` with `android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView`.
On fragment view creation I need to show `SwipeRefreshLayout` animation. But when I call `setRefreshing(true)` nothing happens. But when I refresh data animation changes.
I suppose that the animation isn't showing without child inside `SwipeRefreshLayout`.
How to show this animation in the best way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks, guys.

I`ve just realised that the easiest solution is to call method measure(int, int) with non-zero values) before calling setRefreshing(true).  The problem is happening because setRefreshing(true) is calling before onMeasure.

So you need to call:

```
swipeRefreshLayout.measure(initialWidth, initialHeight);
swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(true);
```

Comment: This is a wrong way to do it because you will run into various NPEs.

Comment: @TadasŠubonis Can you explain what NPE you'd get from this? I dont see the issue?

Comment: Also @Maksym what did you use for the values on measure?

Comment: In my case it (SwipeRefreshLayout) contained a RecyclerView and on calling .measure() it will propogate to RecyclerView internals and then a NPE would be thrown. Don't have a stack available at hand now...

Comment: @TadasŠubonis maybe you called `measure` before setting the layout manager in `RecyclerView`.

Answer (score 10):

This is a reported bug (reported [here](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=77712)) and a workaround is available:

```
mSwipeRefreshLayout.setProgressViewOffset(false, 0,
    (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(
        TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 
        24, 
        getResources().getDisplayMetrics()));
mSwipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(true);
```

Answer (score 2):

It depends on which API level you're building under - if you're using up to API 20 then you can just turn on setRefreshing(true), this will run the animation in the ActionBar, but in API 21 (Material Design) they changed the progress to be a spinner than is "pulled into view" before it spins

You have 2 ways of getting around this in API 21:
1) shift the spinner down with setProgressViewOffset(), but remember to shift it back up afterwords (note that this works in px, while setDistanceToTriggerSync() uses dp)
2) make a duplicate spinner that is displayed when you're loading the data

The more code-efficient solution is to use the existing spinner, but you have to be careful that you do reset its position

If you need to calculate the pixel density, you can grab it from:

```
DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
activity.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
float scale = metrics.density;
```

Answer (score 1):

SwipeRefreshLayout must contain a child to work properly. Make sure you initialize it before using it anywhere!

Answer (score 0):

you must call `setRefreshing(true)` after `onDraw()`, else it would not display animation.

so, in Activity, you can do it in `onCreate()`, like this:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // other codes

    new Handler().post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(true);
            refreshing = true;
            refreshData();
        }
    }
}
```

in fragment, you can put these codes in `onActivityCreated()`.