# SwipeRefreshLayout is hidden on empty RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-appcompat, android-recyclerview, swiperefreshlayout

I have a `Fragment` with a `SwipeRefreshLayout` and then `RecyclerView` as child.
When the Fragment is committed, it starts talking to a server in order to retrieve some data and populate a CustomAdapter which will serve the RecyclerView.

The user can refresh the content by swiping down or pressing a button on the ActionBar. In the latter case, I manually call `swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(true)`. So no troubles until now.

The problem arises when I manually call the refresh state during the first loading of the RecyclerView (`onStart()`).
The progress indicator is not showed up and I assume because the RecyclerView is still empty since it requires some seconds to retrieve all the data...

I leave you some code.

**Fragment code:**

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment implements SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener {


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View mView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_stop, container, false);
        mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) mView.findViewById(R.id.recyclerView1);
        mRecyclerView.addItemDecoration(new DividerItemDecoration(getActivity(),
             DividerItemDecoration.VERTICAL_LIST));
        mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
        mRecyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());

       //SwipeRefreshLayout retrieved and  configured
       swipeLayout = (SwipeRefreshLayout) mView.findViewById(R.id.swipe_container);
       swipeLayout.setOnRefreshListener(this);
       swipeLayout.setColorSchemeResources(
            R.color.primaryColor,
            R.color.cyan_500,
            R.color.light_green_500,
            R.color.amber_500);

        return mView;


     }

    ...
    @Override
        public void onStart() {
            super.onStart();
            executeSchedule(); //First execution and data loading.
        }
        ...

    @Override
    public void onRefresh() {
        executeSchedule();
    }
    ...
    public void executeSchedule() {
        new Schedule().execute();
    }



    private class Schedule extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        ...
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            if(!swipeLayout.isRefreshing()) {
                swipeLayout.setRefreshing(true); //set refresh state
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        ...
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            adap = new CustomAdapter(getActivity(), ...);
            mRecyclerView.setAdapter(adap);
            swipeLayout.setRefreshing(false);
        }

}
```

**XML code:**

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/section_label"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

        <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:id="@+id/swipe_container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/recyclerView1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:paddingLeft="4dp"
                android:paddingRight="4dp"
                android:paddingBottom="2dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:divider="#e0e0e0"
                tools:context=".MyFragment" />

        </android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

What would be the best practice to address this situation?
Adding a second dummy SwipeRefreshLayout? Immediately force an empty adapter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to call measure method before call `setRefreshing(true)`.
Take a look at: [SwipeRefreshLayout no animation on fragment creation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26692841/2114930). Maybe it can be helpful.

Comment: Thank you. I didn't know that.
For sure it is a far better solution than calling `setProgressViewOffset()`

Answer (score 17):

I had a problem with `SwipeRefreshLayout` not working with an empty recycler, so I created a very simple empty adapter.

```
public class EmptyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {
    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: How do you use it?

Comment: mRecyclerView.setAdapter(new EmptyAdapter());

Answer (score 7):

I just wrap RecyclerView with RelativeLayout inside SwipeRefreshLayout and the problem is solved.

```
<android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/swipeContainer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
<RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

</android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
</RelativeLayout>
</android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Comment: Thanks!!! This solution very useful in my case (first cell of RecyclerView is hidden)